# R - Pick out documents from VCorpus (or TermDocumentMatrix) containing key words

Tags: r, keyword

I have a list of keywords in a text file:

```
tagSrc <- "20171107 keyword dictionary v2.txt"
tagDictionary <- readLines(tagSrc, encoding="UTF-8")
```

...and I have a .csv file full of event reports, which I turn into a `VCorpus` and `TermDocumentMatrix`:

```
srcFile <- "20170831 Event Log April 17.csv"
incidents <- read.csv(srcFile, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
descriptions <- incidents$Description

desc_source <- VectorSource(descriptions)
desc_corpus <- VCorpus(desc_source)
desc_corpus <- tm_map(desc_corpus, removeNumbers)
desc_corpus <- tm_map(desc_corpus, removeWords, c(stopwords("en"))

#Various text-cleaning routines
desc_corpus <- tm_map(desc_corpus, content_transformer(replace_abbreviation))
desc_corpus <- tm_map(desc_corpus, content_transformer(replace_contraction))

desc_stem <- tm_map(desc_corpus, content_transformer(stemDocument), language="english")

#Here, the corpus is turned into a TDM
desc_dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(desc_stem, control = list(dictionary = tagDictionary))
```

The last line above gives me a TDM which only uses the terms in the list of key words (`tagDictionary`). Is there a way I could also reduce the number of documents, to only those which contain one or more of the key words?

Answer (score 0):

After more searching around, I found that the best way to do this is to reduce the number of documents *before* constructing the TDM. Running a `grep` search on the corpus via `tm_filter` picks out the documents:

```
#collapse the search terms in `tagDictionary` into a single string:
allTags<-paste(tagDictionary, collapse='|')

#filter the VCorpus (see code in OP):
corp_subset <- tm_filter(desc_stem, function(i), any(grep(allTags, content(i), ignore.case = TRUE)))

#create the TDM from the filtered VCorpus:
desc_dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corp_subset)
```